# What happened? Suspended for "inappropriate content"

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

So, this is a bit odd, and I'm not even sure what happened.

I was in the javascript chat room, when I said, "cyber bullying isn't even a real thing".

Now, whether or not you agree with what I said (from my ban, I can tell most people do not), An instant ban without a kick seems a bit hasty. I was given no warning, and nobody even seemed upset by this claim.

The message was deleted, however: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/26774763/history

I've no idea what happened, unless chat auto-bans anyone that mentions cyber bullying, lol.

Did a moderator suspend me? Did *someone*? Everyone in the room seems equally confused.

For the record, it was a 30 minute susepension, of which has passed; so this is just a question as to what happened; no actions are required on behalf of mods, etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Did a moderator suspend me? Did *someone*? Everyone in the room seems equally confused.

When a user is suspended from chat by a moderator, it will say so. If it says that you've been suspended for "inappropriate content", that means the content was spam-/offensive-flagged to oblivion, resulting in your suspension. Every message that gets deleted this way adds 30 minutes to the automatic suspension.

Moderators can place chat suspensions of arbitrary lengths, much like they can on the main site. They can also lift both automatic and manual suspensions.

Comment: Thirty minutes isn't, in my view, a draconian penalty for content that the SO hivemind decides is inappropriate. It's enough to douse a nasty flame war, but not so much that a joke is cause for long-term ostracism.

Comment: We thought it was flags, but none of us actively chatting saw any flags raised on the comment.

Comment: I was also present during this period, and no flag was ever raised (visible to me) on said message.

Answer (score 40):

This is what happens [when a *flag* is raised on your chat message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#nice). And then *x* other people across the Stack Exchange chat network validate the flag. You get a 30 minute suspension and your message is destroyed.

While you may enjoy a bit of good humour with your mates in your chat room, remember that you are still on Stack Exchange and all transcripts are public. Being a "cyber bully denier" at a time when we should all be trying to stamp out cyber bullying is probably not a very good idea, as you've discovered.

Please take a moment to read the chat FAQ (I've linked to it above) to discover how chat works, and keep your chat contributions professional/civil/mature.